# Mathematica Not Responding

Tags: crash

The problem I meet is when I try to edit the code in .nb file, the Mathematica often crash and "Not responding" shows after the file name in the top line, especially when I want to copy some code with mouse. Generally, I need to wait for a while then edit the code again. Then the problem still exists. There is no such problem before. My system is Windows 8 (64) and I have tried Mathematica 10.0 and 10.2.

Is there anybody having the same problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: Is there a dynamic code in you notebook?

Comment: Do you have the `Suggestions Bar` enabled? See [Don't leave the Suggestions Bar enabled](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75284/9362)

Comment: When the front-end hangs up, try killing the kernels (all processes called `WolframKernel.exe`) via the Task Manager. This often solves the problem for me.